# GlobalFilter shows empty rows

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am new to react table and i used a global filter but as soon as i type anything in search, all the rows disappear..

```
GlobalFilter.js
  <MDBox width="12rem" ml="auto">
        <MDInput
          placeholder="Search..."
          value={filter || ""}
          size="small"
          fullWidth
          onChange={(e) => {
            setFilter(e.target.value);
            console.log(filter);
          }}
        />
      </MDBox>
    </>

const tableInstance = useTable(
    { columns, data, initialState: { pageIndex: 0 } },
    // useFilters,
    useGlobalFilter,
    useSortBy,
    usePagination
  );

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    rows,
    page,
    pageOptions,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    preGlobalFilteredRows,
    setPageSize,
    setGlobalFilter,
    //state,
    // pageIndex,
    // pageSize,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize, globalFilter },
  } = tableInstance;


//some code
 <>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={globalFilter || ""}
                onChange={(e) => setGlobalFilter(e.target.value)}
              />
            </>
```

All the rows disappear, when something is entered in the search. PLease help?
The global filter is coming correctly but the filtered rows are not being shown

Comment: Is this using React Table? Or some other library? If so please include that in your question as a tag otherwise it's just a guessing game because `useTable()` is not a standard hook.

Comment: it is using react table